# Modeling a restaurant menu with django

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a website with a collection of menus from restaurants in my town (since none of them seem to be on grubhub or the internet). I am having trouble creating a model for this. As you know every restaurant menu has sections(I.e Appetizers, Chicken, Steak) and entries under each section(I.e under Appetizers: Mozzarella Sticks, Nachos, etc.) I am trying to create a `Menu` model so that each section of the menu and all of its entries can automatically fill a template:

```
    <h1>{{section}}</h1> <!--I.e:"Appetizers"-->
    <p>{{food}} </p><!--I.e:"Mozzarella Sticks"-->
    <p>{{ food_details }}</p>
```

With the above template, I can use a loop to loop through each section, then another inner loop to loop through each `food` and `food_details` belonging to that specific `section`, but I am not sure how to model this properly:

```
from django.db import models


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10)


    def __str__(self):
        return "%s the place" % self.name

class Menu(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.OneToOneField(
        Restaurant,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    # not sure how to build menu fields 

    #if I do the following each menu will only have one of these fields, which will not work:
    section = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    food = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    food_details = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

How can I create a model of a menu that has multiple `section`'s and multiple `food` and `food_details` entries under each `section`? I hope this made sense, let me know if there is anything I can add and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your models need to be normalized. You can do either
Restaurants(n)->Menu_header(n)->MenuItem
or 
Restaurants(n)->MenuItem(n)<-Menu_header

Comment: didn't even know about this approach, thanks reading into it now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
# models.py
FOOD_TYPES = (
          ('appetizer', 'appetizer'),
          ('entree', 'entree'),
          ('dessert', 'dessert'),
)

class FoodItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=FOOD_TYPES)

class Menu(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.OneToOneField(
        Restaurant,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )

    food_items = models.ManyToManyField(FoodItem)
```

In a view:

```
# views.py
class Restaurant(TemplateView):
    model = Restaurant
    template_name = 'name'

    ...

    def get_context_data
        context = super(Menu, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(name='McDonalds')
        context['restaurant'] = Restaurant.objects.get(name='McDonalds')
        context['menu'] = Menu.objects.get(restaurant=restaurant)
        return context
```

In the template:

```
# template.html
<h1>{{ restaurant.name }}</h1>
 <h2>Menu</h2>

    {% for item in menu.food_items %}
     {% if item.type = 'appetizer' %}
      <p>
       {{ item.name }}
       {{ item.description }}
       {{ item.type }}
      </p>
     {% else %}
      <p>No appetizers</p>
     {% endif %}

     {% if item.type = 'entree' %}
      <p>
       {{ item.name }}
       {{ item.description }}
       {{ item.type }}
      </p>
     {% else %}
      <p>No entrees</p>
     {% endif %}

     {% if item.type = 'dessert' %}
      <p>
       {{ item.name }}
       {{ item.description }}
       {{ item.type }}
      </p>
     {% else %}
      <p>No dessert</p>
     {% endif %}

   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think you can also make Food Type a model also, so that he can add or delete different types from admin panel.